# three buttons on bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get a Bootstrap (most recent version) modal to use a third button in the footer.

```
<div class="modal-footer">
   <button type="button" id="btn-remove" class="btn btn-danger" >Del</button>
   <button type="button" id="close-btn" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
   <button type="button" id="save-btn" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</div>
```

However the javascript environment keeps complaining that I am attaching a click event to an element which doesn't implement the  HTMLElement interface. WTH? I use exactly the same techinque to wire up the other two buttons, binding with jQuery to the buttono element by id:

```
$('#close-btn').on('click', self.clear_modal_values);
$('#save-btn').on('click',  self.save_modal_values);
$('#btn-remove').on('click', self.remove_exceptions);
```

Is there something inherently different about the `btn-danger` treatment ? Or something else obvious I have screwed up?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the provided code. What happens when you `console.log( $('#btn-remove') );`?

Comment: `Object[button#btn-remove.btn.btn-danger]`  - good question though.

Comment: Can you reproduce on JSFiddle with a minimal example? Your code looks good, my guess would be something else on the page is somehow breaking this. If the `#btn-remove` is the only button, can you bind an event to it?

Comment: JSFiddle illustration [http://jsfiddle.net/RoaringSky/okbykyyg/5/] - caveat: jsfiddle doesn't like modals much... Reload to redisplay modal.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the error was elsewhere, and this was merely the point at which it popped through.